# Serial number with alphabetes and numbers

Tags: php

Need PHP alphanumeric count that starts from A001 and goes uptill ZZ999

It starts from A001 and goes on like A002, A003 .....

and after A999 - it changes to B001 and so on till ZZ999

my code is work for only A999 to Z999.

how can this be done ... ?

Can anyone here help me out ..?

thanks in advance !!

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    foreach (range(1, 100) as $number) {
            echo $letter.str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a for loop, since PHP allows you to increment letters, so you can loop from A to ZZ(See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
for ($letter = 'A'; $letter !== 'AAA'; $letter++){
    foreach (range(1, 999) as $number) {
            echo $letter.str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 please edit my post  until I learn do it for other post in future

Comment: Doesn't this stop at ZY100 instead of ZZ999?

Comment: Code is bugged. Not only it stops at `ZY` instead of `ZZ` but it counts up to `100` instead of `999`.

Comment: Yes,i change condition to  `$letter !== 'AAA'` and counter to 999 now worked fine

Comment: @ashkufaraz yuo'd learn faster if you edited your own post `:-p`

Answer (score 2):

```
    for($letters = 'A'; strlen($letters) <= 2; $letters++){
      for($number = 1; $number <= 999; $number++){
      echo $letters.str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).PHP_EOL;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why does it start at `000`?